# Block my activity on Friends' News Feeds like Photo Likes or Post Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

(I am *not* asking how to block my posts on my timeline.)

I am asking how I can block my activity, such as posting in open groups, making comments on people's posts, adding a friend, liking a photo, liking a post, etc., from people seeing it in *their* news feeds?  I don't want people seeing my interactions with other people.

Answer (score 1):

In short: You can't. Currently, there is no way to completely hide your activity on Facebook from everybody.

Which bits of your activity that shows up in other people's feeds is based upon the privacy level of the item you are interacting with.

- If John creates a public post and you like it, anyone can see that - and FB may (depending on their super-secret algorithm) publish that to the feeds of your other friends.
- If John creates a friends-only post and you like it, you and John's friends can see that. Facebook may publish that to the feeds of your friends.
- If John creates a friends-only post and tags you - all of your friends (mutual AND non-mutual) can see that post despite it being a friends-only post. If you like it, all of your friends can see that. Facebook may publish that to the feeds of your friends.

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done, unfortunately. Despite people not wanting to have everything they do broadcast to theirs friends' newsfeeds and despite people not wanting to have to manually restrict what they see from each of their friends, Facebook, as usual, insist that they know best and insist upon the current system while completely ignoring the requests and complaints of their users.